# condition expression editor

Tags: usability, filter

I have very amount of complex interdependent data, such as products, documents, orders.
I need to make expression-builder for selecting and filtering(!) data.

I have some ways to do this

1) I can make plain editor based on SQL language.
Simple text field. Nothing else.
In order to do filtering I can introduce keyword such as "FILTER"
But I suppose that this method is bad UI.

2) I can make 3 columns: data field, condition, value.

Using this user can write these conditions
Product.Price > 20
Product.Name = "Salt"

I believe that this method is better than previous, but if I choose this way how can I make filtering?

Is there third method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it like this:

[image]

So the users can read the filters like *normal* sentences, but they don't have to type so much, because everything is a dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two more way to filter the data.

- **Autofilters** -- like in Excel or Google Spreadsheet. It requires minimum effort for most filtering tasks and familiar to an average user. Advantages are minimal input and obviousness.
  [image]
- **Templates** -- most frequent filtering tasks could be called through command buttons as one-click task. It convient for some narrow filtering tasks (i.e. filter today's operations etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Check the answer by [Pasha S](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/28547/pasha-s) to the similar question: [TreeTable as a flexible condition/filter editor](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37237/treetable-as-a-flexible-condition-filter-editor)

Mathematical notation is very readable but you will need to figure out good ways to edit conditions. I think on the same problem and tend to use the [WorkFlowy](http://workflowy.com)’s approach with indenting by Tab and moving items with shortcuts. But it is also possible that I will end up with some kind of text markup.

Comment: I  might be missing something but what does mathematical notation have to do with problem?

Comment: It is better for understanding complex logical interrelations.