# What is the best way to build visual boolean queries?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, interface, workflow

What are some good examples of building complex boolean queries? The requirements for the interface would be:

1. The user is able to use AND, OR, and NOT statements
2. The user is able to next queries in a flexible manner. For example, "(X AND Y) OR (A OR B OR C AND D) NOT E OR F"

The user would need to make many queries in order to build up complex rule sets using these boolean expressions.

Comment: Hi Nicholas - There's some great answers to a similar question about [Intuitive interface for Composing Boolean Logic?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/intuitive-interface-for-composing-boolean-logic)